# How to align Copyright section in blogger website footer in center?

Tags: html, blogger

Can anyone please tell me that how to align the copyright words in footer of blogger website with other items there.Please see the attached screenshot for more clarity of this question.I want to make it left center so that it looks good and edited code and written leftcenter but it was still in left bottom

Below  is the code for it-

Copyright (c) 2021 MKT Group All Right Reseved

[Please Look the footer of website for more clarity of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHneI.png)

Comment: Can you provide URL of the website?

Comment: You can use flex to center items very easily. I could help more if you show us the code.

Answer (score 1):

you most enter every code in one tag like main and set style for main tag for example :

```
main{
width : 100%;
direction : ltr;
text-align: left;
}
```

and you most set css style for footer in main tag like this :

```
main footer{
 width : 100%;
}

main footer p{
width : 100%;
text-align : left OR right OR center;
display : block;
margin-top : 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
footer p {
margin-top:-3px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
<p>Copyright (c) 2021 MKT Group All Right Reseved</p>
</footer>
```

Change the

```
margin-top: according to your website
```